# Delete a duplicate row if the value of the other column is "Not Completed" or "Empty"

Tags: vba

I m beginner in VBA and I want to delete a duplicate row in column A, if the column of other value is "Not Completed" or "Empty"

I use the following piece of code  to delete the "No completed" or "Empty" but i couldn't figure out how to find a duplicate value and whose other column value is "Not completed"

If Range("f" & p).Value = "Not Completed" or Range("f" & p).Value = "" Then Rows(p).Delete  (this works for deletion of a row)

I used the following function as part of code but its syntax error 
  If WorksheetFunction.Countif(A:A,A2)>1 then (to find duplicate)

like this 
    Dim p As Long

```
For p = Range("f1").End(xlDown).Row To 1 Step -1
If WorksheetFunction.Countif(A:A,A2)>1 then
If Range("f" & p).Value = "Not Completed" or Range("f" & p).Value = "" Then Rows(p).Delete

Next p
```

EX

ColA |   ColB |    colF

21    |  456   |   Pass

25    |  673   | Pass

21    |  679    | Not completed - Delete

22     |  568   | Pass

22     |  367   | Not Completed - Delete

25     | 456    | Empty cell    - Delete

Answer (score 1):

Try this (if there are duplicates of column A values and both have pass in column F, then it is not deleted):

```
Sub SO_18996725()
    Dim p As Long
    ' Start from last row of used range
    For p = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row To 1 Step -1
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A:A"), Range("A" & p)) > 1 Then
            If (InStr(1, Range("F" & p).Text, "Not Completed", vbTextCompare) > 0) Or IsEmpty(Range("F" & p)) Then
                Debug.Print "Delete row: " & p
                Rows(p).Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next p
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A:A"), Range("A3")) > 1
```

However, there are some problems with your code.

1) You are using `End(xlDown)` for looping. In your example, since the last row of Column F is empty, `End(xlDown)` will return the second last row instead. Better use another column.

2) Do you need to reconsider your string matching mechanism? For example

```
?"Not completed"="Not Completed"
False
```

So in your case, the row 21 | 679 | Not completed will not be deleted. If there are any trailing spaces, the comparison will also return false.

3) `WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A:A"), Range("A3"))`

You should change your second argument accordingly as you loop through the rows concerned.

e.g. By using `Offset`